# How to avoid overlapping text in two paragraphs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `<p>` tags. How can I let the 2nd `<p>` tag overflow but not overlap the 1st `<p>` tag.

Below is an example of what I a want to do

`<p>Heading</p> - <p>Text text text text text text text text 
                  text text</p>`

Comment: Please share the HTML you are using and the CSS you have applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the contrary to SteffPoint. You should never use html tables for the structure of your web page. What I would suggest you to do is to place both your paragraphs each in its own div so they have their own block and then float them left next to each other. For this, the most important thing is the width of the block. Make sure the width of the div is small enough so that when you float, the bottom div slides up. I usually use the "%" sign so it adapts to the size of the window.

```css
/*  CSS */
/* This border is simply to see the block you have around each paragraph */
.Block {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 2px;
 margin: 2px;
  width: 40%;
}

.adjacentBlock {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="help.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <div class="Block adjacentBlock">
   <p>This is your first paragraph inside the div</p>
 </div>

 <div class="Block adjacentBlock">
   <p>This is your second paragraph inside the div</p>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, if you wanted a heading on the left side you should use the <h> element instead of the <p> it wont change anything besides the styling of your text. Just make sure you include the classes in the div. I hope this helped out.

Comment: Exacty what I was looking for!! Thank you